# Is it possible to make my own callback for a certain static variable?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes function has built-in `callback` function, "This function is called when something happens"

In my case, I want to make `callback function which is called after a certain static value is changed`

For example,

```
class MyVariable(){
    static myVal = 1;
}


const FileUploader = (props) =>{
    myAlert(){
       console.log("val is changed!"); 
    }
    changeValue2(){
      MyVariable.myVal = 2;
      myAlert();
      
    }
    changeValue3(){
      MyVariable.myVal = 3; 
      myAlert();
    } 
    changeValue4(){
      MyVariable.myVal = 4; 
      myAlert();
    } 
}
```

I want to call `myAlert()` after `myVal` is changed.

so currently I write `myAlert()` third times.

I wonder is it possible to do this automatically like making the callback `which is called when myVal is changed`

Is there any way for this idea? I am using `React`

Comment: This has nothing to do with React.

Comment: Since `.myVal` is a property, not a variable, you can definer a setter that calls `myAlert()`

Comment: Maybe create a setter instead?

Answer (score 2):

You could define a setter and use a private field to store the value.

```js
class MyVariable {
    static #myVal = 1;
    static get myVal() {
        return MyVariable.#myVal;
    }
    static set myVal(newVal) {
        if (newVal !== MyVariable.#myVal) {
            console.log('changing myVal to', newVal); // or call myAlert()
            MyVariable.#myVal = newVal;
        }
    }
}
console.log(MyVariable.myVal);
MyVariable.myVal = 2;
console.log(MyVariable.myVal);
```

Comment: and then if we do again `MyVariable.myVal = 2`, it repeat `changing myVal to 2` ? but this is them value, and there is no change... ;)

Comment: @MisterJojo Good point. I've updated it now.

Comment: This embeds the _alert_ function into the `MyVariable` class itself but OP appears to want that implementation separate

Answer (score 1):

You can change `myVal` to a [*setter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) and also allow registering of *listeners* or *subscribers*. Then, when the value is changed, call the listeners from within the setter.

```js
class MyVariable {
  static #subscribers = [];
  static #myVal = 1;
  
  static set myVal(newVal) {
    const oldVal = this.#myVal;
    
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
      this.#myVal = newVal;
      this.#subscribers.forEach((listener) => {
        listener(oldVal, newVal);
      });
    }
  }
  
  static get myVal() {
    return this.#myVal;
  }
  
  static subscribe(listener) {
    const idx = this.#subscribers.push(listener) - 1;
    
    // return an unsubscribe function
    return () => {
      this.#subscribers.splice(idx, 1);
    };
  }
}

const unsub = MyVariable.subscribe((oldVal, newVal) => {
  console.log(`val is changed! From ${oldVal} to ${newVal}`);
});

MyVariable.myVal = 2;
MyVariable.myVal = 3;

unsub();
MyVariable.myVal = 4; // no alert after unsubscribe
```